# How to test Spouts in Storm

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am struggling with a task to unit test my Apache Storm spout which actually reads from a queue and emits a message as a tuple. I want to use embedded queue, put a message onto the queue and asset that message is emitted by my spout. Could anyone help what to use to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a ton of ways you can do this but here is an example of a simple test using mockito and testng (\src\test\java\com\example\storm\spout\DummySpoutTest.java):

```
package com.example.storm.spout;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyList;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import backtype.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;

import com.example.storm.spout.DummySpout;

public class DummySpoutTest {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
    public void shouldCreateDummyMessage() {
        // given
        DummySpout spout = new DummySpout();
        SpoutOutputCollector collector = mock(SpoutOutputCollector.class);
        spout.open(null, null, collector);

        // when
        spout.nextTuple();

        // then
        verify(collector).emit(anyList());
    }

}
```